# Riemannian geometry and Symmetries, Hyperbolic Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, symmetry, general-relativity

I am currently trying to connect Hyperbolic geometry through several models with Riemannian geometry. At first I have transformed the metric tensor from sphere in $R^3$ and the pseudo-sphere in $R^{2,1}$  through stereographic projection, complex transformations etc. After that I am trying to transform the induced symmetries(independent Killing vectors) of  $R^3$ and $R^{2,1}$ on the sphere and pseudo-sphere in all these several coordinate system. This process is supposed to reveal the Riemannian structure of hyperbolic spaces. I need some help to make the connection. Thank you

Comment: This is rather a vague request. Where exactly are you in this big project? Can you ask an explicit mathematical question regarding a place where you are stuck?

Comment: Let me suggest that you take [the tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), and that you read about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: My problem is that I cannot understand why the independent killing vectors expressed in all these different coordinate systems (conformal after a point because of the stereographic projection), help me see the Riemannian structure of the Hyperbolic space. The idea of the project is Hyperbolic spaces , group perspective and differential/Riemannian geometry perspective. Somehow the transformations I computed give me the various elements I need. I know it is vague.. There is something I cannot see

Comment: I strongly recommend this: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/RFG/cannon.pdf. They don't seem to mention Killing vectors explicitly, but they discuss very clearly how the different models of hyperbolic space are connected.

Comment: Do some reading as Deane suggested and try to ask a more focused question so that an answer does not require one to write an expository paper.